# cmd closes when i run flutter,flutter doctor

Tags: flutter, installation

Program 'flutter.bat' failed to run: The system cannot find the file specifiedAt line:1 char:1

- flutter doctor v
- 

At line:1 char:1

- flutter doctor v
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
  ```

this is the error showing in the powershell, i have done env path and every thing

help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the flutter and dart paths are correctly added to the system's PATH env variable.

if so, try to run commands from the Flutter installation directory
a friend of mine once faces that kind of issue, spent 2weeks then figured out that theres a firewall software blocking (interferring) this execution somehow,

so maybe you gotta check your antivirus/firewall settings and provide excepional configurations for flutter

Comment: i tried with another pc ...it is working but not in mine ......i have only windows basic firewall